# Game Maker Studio custom game launcher for resolution

Tags: windows, batch-file, game-maker-studio-1.4

So I've been working on a game in game maker studio (standard edition,the game I'm making is for windows) for some time now.It's been going fine,however when I turn on fullscreen all the graphics become very fuzzy and distorted.I found a fix to this by turning of interpolation in the global settings,but in doing so now the sprites look torn when in fullscreen.The game view is 1024 x 768.I know that my problem is caused by the fact that the graphics are being increased unevenly.So I thought i could create a custom game launcher which set the screen resolution (not the game resolution,but the actual screen resolution of windows) to be 1024 x 768 and then switch back when the game closes.I did that using a batch file I converted into an .exe and a program called "QRes.exe" and that worked out fine,but my problem is that the program "QRes.exe" is copyrighted (there's a copyright message in the console when you use it),so I won't be able to use it when i release my game eventually.

So is there a way to create a custom launcher for my game,that changes the screen resolution to 1024 x 768 and then back to the resolution that is was before without using any copyrighted programs like this one

Here's the code that I used with "QRes.exe" (Note that I'm not expirienced with batch files,I found the code for getting the current screen resolution on this site,the rest i wrote myself,since it involves very little knowledge of batch files and is very simple code)

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%# in  ('"wmic path Win32_VideoController  get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value"') do (
  set "%%#">nul
)

echo %CurrentHorizontalResolution%
echo %CurrentVerticalResolution%

QRes.exe /x:1024 /y:768

"GAME.exe"

QRes.exe /x:%CurrentHorizontalResolution% /y:%CurrentVerticalResolution%
```

Comment: QRes is freeware. You can distribute it with your script, you just have to give them credit and not receive any money for your script.

Comment: Also, PowerShell can call the Win32 API, which can change your desktop resolution.

Comment: Well there's the problem,what if I want to sell my game? I can't because it's copyrighted.I'm looking for a program which isn't or a way to do it which doesn't involve a copyrighted program.I'm going to check out what you said about powershell altough I don't know if I could create a game launcher with that.

Comment: If you're planning on selling it, I'd recommend actually fixing your game so that it runs correctly in resolutions above 1024x768. I've been using 1920x1080 for years now and if I found out the game I bought was limited to a resolution that I haven't used since XP, I'd be asking for a refund.

Comment: Well I thnk it would look a lot nicer if the resolution just changes rather than having a black border around the outside.Besides I would have to make every sprite in such a way that it that it only scales by rounded numbers so that it doesn't have a tearing effect which is a lot more work than it sounds,especially for a one man project.Idk I might figure out something else.

Comment: Allright I managed to make it work by creating a couple of resolution    (320 x 240,640 x 480.960 x 720,1280 x 960)options into the game,guess ill just resize all sprites to the smallest one so that they upscale smoothly,oh well,it's not that much work i'm sure I'll get it done.Do you think the sizes are good enough to suit most resolutions? Or should i maybe decrease the smallest one and include one more size.